# WooCommerce: Add class to Related Product Loop item <ul class="products columns-4 owl-carousel four-col">

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to add some Owl Carousel Classes to the Related Products from `<ul class="products columns-4">` to `<ul class="products columns-4 owl-carousel four-col">` in the Unordered List, in the single product page.

The CSS classes I want to add are `owl-carousel four-col`.

Doing this I know requires some knowledge of WordPress hooks and filters.

Any idea on how to implement this will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no filter available to modify classes set to `<ul class="products">` element.

This element is actually rendered with WC template `templates/loop/loop-start.php` and this template is called with `woocommerce_product_loop_start()` function. This is a pluggable function, meaning you can override it in your active theme/child-theme.

The **better and simpler way** would be to modify the `related` template directly, located in `templates/single-product/related.php` (learn [how to properly override](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) WC templates in your child-theme, do **NOT** modify WC source templates directly in plugin's folder).

It should be enough to replace this line in the `related` template:

`<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>`

with this line:

`<ul class="products columns-4 owl-carousel four-col">`

---

Another approach would be to set those classes dynamically with jQuery, but I'm not sure whether it would work well with Owl Carousel (it might not load properly).